# Downloading files from static links with C#

Tags: c#, download

I am needing to download a file from [this page](http://fhfa.gov/Default.aspx?Page=296) when the files are updated each quarter. I am building an automated process to use the data from one of the files and I would like to automate the download as well.

What are my options? is there any way easier than screen scraping? the links are said to be static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are really static (i.e. never change), you could do something like this:

```
var links = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "http://fhfa.gov/weblink/POSummary.xls", @"c:\temp\POSummary.xls" },
                { "...", "..."}
            };
var webClient = new WebClient();
foreach (var kvp in links)
{
    webClient.DownloadFile(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Or with one file even easier:

```
webClient.DownloadFile("[address]", "[fileName]");
```

Comment: From the title of the page "Static Links to Most Current HPI Data" I think this solution will work best.

Comment: based on the comments at the top of the link I posted... Do you think they are telling the truth about them never changing? ;)

Comment: "These perma-links would be helpful for users attempting to automate the regular download of the most recent data." Seems like others had the same need as you do and they acknowledged that. To be absolutely future proof, you could get the link from some kind of resource file and if it ever changes (which according to the site it wont) you would just update that resource file.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way easier than screen scraping?

No, there isn't, unless the site provides you with an API that would allow you to return the available files to be downloaded in for example JSON format.